# asp.net fullcalendar example using web forms

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, fullcalendar

I am planning to create a scheduler like application using Jquery FullCalendar plugin.
Searched a bit, but there are examples using only asp.net mvc.

Is there a good tutorial for creating scheduler using asp.net web forms plus using sql server for storing events?

Answer (score 4):

I had created a fullcalendar web app using asp.net web forms, using sql server to store events.

Just uploaded it to google code so you can download it.

here's the link:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar-asp-net/

tell me if it works for you.